# gitpython fetch get chinese named branch get encoding error

Tags: python, gitpython

Python version 3.11.3
When I use gitpython, my codes like below

```
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"
os.environ["PYTHONUFT8"] = "on"

repo = Repo(repo_path)
remote = repo.remote()
remote.fetch()
```

if there is a branch named with Chinese like "测试分支", it will throw error

```py
git.exc.CommandError: Cmd('<stderr-pump>') failed due to: UnicodeDecodeError(''gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 54: illegal multibyte sequence')
```

I know it's an encoding problem, I've already set `PYTHONUTF8=1` and `PYTHONIOENCODING='utf-8'`,but it doesn't work.

1. Does `fetch` method have any params like `encoding='utf-8'`?
2. How could I use fetch with utf-8?
3. Why does it auto choose gbk?

Answer (score 0):

Tried newest Gitpython, fetch doesn't throw the error no more. However, `remote().fetch().name` and other parts remain GBK encoding.

So far from what I can try, the best to walk around this is to:
`str(bytes(remote().fetch().name,'gbk'), encoding='utf-8')`

Update:
Suppose this error only happens in Windows. In order to make GitPython not to use gbk as default codec, you can change Windows settings: inside Time and languages -> Languages and areas -> Manage language settings -> Management tab -> None Unicode programme and language -> Change -> Check Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 to support global language support and restart. Which should work afterwards.